# How to parse XML with other fields into multiple lines in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table with data fields. One of the fields is of type XML. The stored XMLs have at least one node with sub elements that I need to extract.

Example table row:

```
Id  UserId  Date        XML
1   1001    2019-02-13  *
```

*XML =

```
<root>
    <action>
        <type>1</type>
        <res>0</res>
    </action>
    <action>
        <type>1</type>
        <res>10</res>
    </action>
    <action>
        <type>2</type>
        <res>-5</res>
    </action>
</root>
```

I know how to get individual values with XML.value and how to parse all nodes in separate table. I just can't figure out how to combine the two into the result I need.

Expected result:

```
Id  UserId  Date        Type    Res
1   1001    2019-02-13  1        0
1   1001    2019-02-13  1       10
1   1001    2019-02-13  2       -5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CROSS APPLY` on `nodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) is your friend:

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE(Id INT, UserId INT, [Date] DATETIME, [XML] XML);
INSERT @t VALUES (1, 1001, '2019-02-13', N'
<root>
    <action>
        <type>1</type>
        <res>0</res>
    </action>
    <action>
        <type>1</type>
        <res>10</res>
    </action>
    <action>
        <type>2</type>
        <res>-5</res>
    </action>
</root>');

SELECT 
    Id, 
    UserId, 
    [Date], 
    [Type] = [action].value('type[1]', 'int'),
    [Res] = [action].value('res[1]', 'int')
FROM @t 
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('/root/action') actions([action]);
```

Result:

```
+----+--------+-------------------------+------+-----+
| Id | UserId |          Date           | Type | Res |
+----+--------+-------------------------+------+-----+
|  1 |   1001 | 2019-02-13 00:00:00.000 |    1 |   0 |
|  1 |   1001 | 2019-02-13 00:00:00.000 |    1 |  10 |
|  1 |   1001 | 2019-02-13 00:00:00.000 |    2 |  -5 |
+----+--------+-------------------------+------+-----+
```